# NSSegmentedControl wrong layouting with Interface Builder Xcode 6.1.1

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, xib, nssegmentedcontrol

I'm trying to put a NSSegmentedControl in a NSWindow but have Problem to put it at right Position. What i want is to lay the NSSegmentedControl direct under the NSToolbar.

The issue:
If i put it direct under the NSToolbar [1] with Interface Builder, the NSSegmentedControl will not be shown. But if i change the position of NSSegmentedControl as in photo [2]. How can i put the NSSegmentedControl at right position?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7qbq.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFAQn.png

Answer (score 0):

I'm mainly a mobile developer, and I know that you can fix a similar problem on mobile by putting the Segmented Control inside of an NSView object. Does this work?

Comment: It's not work because the NSSegmentedControl is already put in default NSView of the NSWindow.

Comment: What happens when you make a new NSView? Does it not let you put in the SegmentedControl?

Comment: The issue is that i create the .xib with Autolayout features and didn't set the constraints to the elements inside the NSView. And now it's solved.